# How to get unit test results in the browser with Laravel.

Tags: laravel

I would like to see the results of individual unit tests in the browser.  I would like to do something like...

```
public function test() {
    $test = new \Tests\Unit\ExampleTest();
    dd($test->testBasicTest());
}
```

That just returns null.  I also tried `exec('vendor/bin/phpunit');` but would like to stay away from exec() (and to mention, that snippet creates an endless loop for some reason).

Comment: just a remark: probably due to  `testBasicTest` not having a return (nothing to `dd()` )

Answer (score 0):

What if you try doing a echo of your dd?

```
public function test() {
    $test = new \Tests\Unit\ExampleTest();
    echo(dd($test->testBasicTest()));
}
```

Comment: this question is specific to Laravel dd() gives output.